# Session Cookie Not Expiring in Android

Tags: android, session, cookies

I have a mobile and a desktop version of my site, and I automatically redirect mobile users who arrive on the desktop site to the mobile site.

When a mobile user requests a specific url on the desktop site, the redirection is bypassed so they can go to the desktop version of the site for the remainder of the session. To facilitate this, we set a session cookie on the desktop site--if that cookie's present, we bypass redirection, if not, we redirect to mobile.

This method works correctly with iPhones and with Android user agent simulators on the desktop; however, with the 2 android phones we tested, the redirection bypass continues after the session ends and only stops after we specifically remove the cookies. We tried force quitting the browser, clearing the browser cache, and even powering the phone off entirely.

What ends a session in Android? Is it browser/device-specific?

Are session cookies supported in Android?

Is there any way to view cookie values and expiration details?

Is there another recommended method for getting the functionality described above across all devices?

If anyone has any good documentation describing the expected behaviors and recommendations, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Which devices did this occur on? And did you test your site with the Android emulators?

Comment: We tested on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and a Motorola Droid Razr. I have not tested with an emulator but will give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, we still haven't had time to resolve this issue. If anyone can get to it, please do share! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered some problems for myself in this field.

On an Xperia Ray the closing of the Browser app did not end the session. In a Sammsung tab it will.

To test, if a cookie is set on a mobile device, you should use something similar to 'weinre' (Adobe Phonegap uses it, too, I think)